# FM16 Active Tab Information Passthrough

Tags: filemaker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG1An.png)Essentially I have a tab panel. There are three tabs. Tab one is inventory items, tab two and three are separate portals that show captured signatures. I need help creating a button that opens my signature capture window, passes through that Sig1/sig2 tab was active/ had focus, and returns the captured signature to the portal in Sig1 tab/ sig2 depending on what is open.

As far as I can tell I would use GetLayoutObjectAttribute, but any information on where to start would be great. Thank you Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.

Use the GetLayoutObjectAttribute ( “Sig1” ; "isFrontPanel" ) statement to test if it is active. Sig1 here is the tab panel’s object name, not title.

Comment: when I use "isFrontPanel" FM says the table does not exist?

Comment: Or more specific that the parameter "isFrontPanel", or "hasFocus" or any of the ones listed on their website do not work as parameters for the function.

Comment: Figured out the quotations were needed haha.

Comment: Now using If [GetLayoutObjectAttribute ("Sig1Tab" ; "IsFrontPanel") = 1]
Go To Layout ["SigCapture" (BillHeader);Animation:None]
Set Field [BillHeader::Sig1]
End If

Answer (score 0):

While this did answer the question I had, the question I had was wrong. What I really needed to ask was "how do you change a container field on entry based on a variable"

Comment: Use the OnObjectModify script trigger.